# django-rest-framework and custom routes

Tags: django, routes, django-rest-framework

I have the following setup.

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'post', PostViewSet)
```

Then in my urlpatterns

```
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

Then in my views.py

```
 class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
```

Now that works perfectly for my use case but I also want to do something like this to grab data from a certain day

```
/api/post/2013/08/09/
```

That would pull out all the data for that current day.. I'm a bit unsure how to do custom routes in django-rest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The part of the Django Rest Framework docs you're looking for is that on [filtering against the URL](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url).

The basic idea is that you override `get_queryset` to return a filtered QuerySet matching parameters you define in your URL conf.

The Django ORM field lookups you'll need are [`year`, `month` and `day`, which start here in the QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year).

I hope that helps.