# Query parameters in the URL, with REST Framework

Tags: django, rest, deserialization

I, stared using REST Framework few days ago, but I, can't find how create a customized url with parameter, in Django this kind of url is written like this.

```
url(r'^author/(?P<author>\d+)/books/$', BooksList.as_view(), name = 'books'),
```

for this

```
http://mysite/author/1/books
```

I, try with:

```
router.register(r'author/(?P<author>\d+)/books', BooksList, base_name = 'Books')
```

but this don't work.

I, see this questions but, don't work:
[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194603/django-rest-custom-url-in-a-modelviewset?rq=1)
[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156291/django-rest-framework-and-custom-routes)

This is my code.

```
# models.py
class Author(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class Book(models.Model):
    Book = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Title


# views.py
class BooksList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Book
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        author = self.kwargs['author']
        queryset = Book.objects.filter(Author = author)
        return queryset

# urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'books', BooksList, base_name = 'Books')

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace = 'rest_framework')),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this reading the tutorial in second part "[Adding optional format suffixes to our URLs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses#adding-optional-format-suffixes-to-our-urls)",

At, last I get url like this:

```
http://localhost:8001/books/author/1/
```

Here is my code.

```
# urls.py
url(r'^books/author/(?P<author>\d+)/$', BooksByAuthor, name='BooksByAuthor'),

# serializer.py
class BooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'Title')

# views.py
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from .serializers import *

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

def BooksByAuthor(request, author):
    try:
        books = Book.objects.filter(Author = author).order_by('Title')
    except Book.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = BooksSerializer(books)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```